# @Mapping on mapstruct with List<> Of List<>

Tags: mapstruct

I've recently started to use mapstruct, while coding I stuck with a scenario. In order to solve the ambiguity between the below default methods, I'm trying to use the "qualifiedBy" on a List<

```
@Mapping(qualifiedBy = LineTestBO). Line => 1
 List<ReturnABO> toCaptureLineItemsBOs(List<LineDTO> lineDTO);

 @Named("LineTestBO")
 default ReturnABO map(LineDTO lineDTO) {
     if (lineDTO.getCurrency() != null && lineDTO.getNationalPermit() != null &&
         lineDTO.getAmount() != null && lineDTO != null)
         return this.toBO(lineDTO);
     return null;
 }

  default returnABO toBO(LineDTO lineDTO)  {
  // To do here
}
```

But Line 1 shows the error as it needs to "target" to be specified. I'm not sure what should be the target here since Line is a collection object. Even If I don't use the @mapping the mapstuct generates the mapper implementation. I read the mapstuct documentation but could not follow much for this scenario. How the Named annotation can be used on List to explicity denote that this is name to be used ? Can someone help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The reason for the error is that using `@Mapping` on iterable mapping method doesn't make much sense.

What you are looking for is `IterableMapping#qualifiedBy`.

So in your case the mapper needs to look like:

```java
@Mapper
public interface MyMapper {

    @IterableMapping(qualifiedByName = "LineTestBO")
    List<ReturnABO> toCaptureLineItemsBOs(List<LineDTO> lineDTO);

    @Named("LineTestBO")
    default ReturnABO map(LineDTO lineDTO) {
        if (lineDTO.getCurrency() != null && lineDTO.getNationalPermit() != null && lineDTO.getAmount() != null && lineDTO != null) {
            return this.toBO(lineDTO);
        }
        
        return null;
     }

    default returnABO toBO(LineDTO lineDTO)  {
         // To do here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

the target must be specified, so if your POJOs look like this

```
class A {
  private List<ReturnABO> x;
}

class B {
  private List<LineDTO> x;
}
```

in your mapper, you could have something like this

```
interface AMapper {
   @Mapping(target="x", source="x", qualifiedByName = "LineTestBO")
   A toA(B b);

   @Named("LineTestBO")
   default List<ReturnABO> lineTestBO (List<LineDTO> lines) {
      return lines.stream().map(this::map).collect(Collectors.toList())
   } 
   default ReturnABO map(LineDTO lineDTO) {
      if (lineDTO.getCurrency() != null && lineDTO.getNationalPermit() != null &&
           lineDTO.getAmount() != null && lineDTO != null)
           return this.toBO(lineDTO);
      return null;
   }
}
```

Comment: A toA(B b); - I'm trying to understand, so what A and B denote here the actual class names? Actually I try to call the toCaptureLineItemsBOs inside a class is MapperInterfaceName. toCaptureLineItemsBOs(). What I need to understand and how this has to be refactored?

I was just trying with some other option, Just applied @Named annotation on the above default method() @Named("LineTestBO")
 default ReturnABO map( and it worked fine with no issues. But the named method was not used by the mapper generater.

Comment: Thanks bbahaida. While I tried implementing your ideas, both List<ReturnABO> & List<LineDTO) resides in the same class here. At this stage, any space them within the same class. 

The aim of mapping is like below.